# Why can't I connect my Sql Server to DOMO?

Tags: sql-server, domo

I've been using PowerBI to create visualisations for my Sql Server data, but it's quite unyielding and clunky in my novice experience.

Deciding to try different solutions, I've given DOMO a try but I'm unable to connect to the database:
[image]

I've checked my firewall settings for my hosted server and they appear to be correct:

[image]

I'm not GREAT when it comes to network stuff, but that seems OK (pretty much the default setup). If I try a port I know definitely isn't right then it says rightly that the TCP/IP connection to the port has failed. I was able to connect with the same details to the Tableau platform, and of course PowerBI (although this latter one was a local connection).

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the SQL Server logs to see if you can see the failed connection attempt? If not, do. Either way, what do the logs say (or perhaps don't)?

Comment: The error says "SQL Server returned Login failed for user". This means you did connect but the login failed. You are unlikely to be able to use a windows login from an externally hosted platform. It's going to need to be a SQL Login.

Comment: The logs don't seem to show anything that would show it's knocked back a request for my attempt. Noted re the SQL login. I'll create one and see if that works. Thanks.

Comment: Using the domo workbench to connect to SQL Server is the easiest way and gives you more flexibility. Also, please remember that the user cannot be using windows authentication and has to be sql login.